# Is it possible to dynamically attach ec2 to stack in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am creating 5 ec2 instances in ansible.
Now i want to attach all those newly created instances in a stack.

Is it possible to do it in ansible after ec2s are created.

I don't want to put much stuff in clouformation. I want to do all stuff via ansible

Comment: can you please provide more details so I can guide you on this.

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_aws.html#provisioning).

Comment: What do you mean here by adding to STACK ? Something to do with cloud formation or you want to add a same  tag named "stack" to all of those instances ?

Comment: @DeepaliMittal yes that is cloudformation stack

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `stack` sub group from `instance_tags` as follow :

```
- name: Launch EC2 instances
  ec2:
    key_name: "{{ key_name }}"
    group: "{{ item.value.security_group }}"
    instance_type: "{{ item.value.instance_type }}"
    instance_tags:
      class: "Name it something"
      stack: "{{ name_prefix }}"
```

`instance_tags` is a hash/dictionary of tags to add to the new instance or for starting/stopping instance by tag; '{"key":"value"}' and '{"key":"value","key":"value"}'

Comment: I am talking about cloudformation stack not normal stack tags